# How to properly syncronize Rx subject `.onNext` calls?

Tags: kotlin, rx-java2

I’m working on a messaging application and would like to have service that exposes a `newMessages` observable. Different parts of the app can subscribe to the observable and display badges for new messages and so on.

I have a couple of restrictions:

1. I cannot have the whole message in the notification payload (some security restrictions). Instead, when I receive a notification with the `uuid`, I ask the server for the message with this `uuid`.
2. Actually, I ask the server for all new messages, I load the last message `uuid` from my local database, and ask the server for all the messages after this `uuid`. I cache all new messages in the local database.

On the first ball, I thought:

1. Initialize a `PublicSubject` called `newMessages`.
2. When the notification arrives, check if you have the message with this `uuid` in the local DB. If yes -> show notification; if no -> load all new messages from the server, store them in the local DB, emit them into `newMessages` subject and display the notification.

Something like this:

```kotlin
private val newMessagesSubject = PublishSubject.create<List<UserMessage>>()
val newMessages = newMessagesSubject.observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())

fun newNotificationArrived(uuid: UUID) {

  fun filterCurrentMessage(messages: List<UserMessage>) = messages
    .firstOrNull { it.uuid == uuid }
    ?: throw IllegalStateException("Can't find a message with id: $uuid")

  /*
   * If we manage to load from the local database, we don't emit because we assume
   * that the request that we emited the messages before storing them into the DB.
   */
  fun loadFromDatabase() = Maybe.fromCallable { messageTable.getMessageWithUuid(uuid) }
  fun loadFromServer(accessCode: String, latestMessageUuid: UUID) =
    messagingApi
      .getUserMessagesAfterUUID(accessCode, latestMessageUuid, null)
      .retryWithExponentialBackoff()
  fun loadCacheEmitAndMap(accessCode: String, latestMessageUuid: UUID) =
    loadFromServer(accessCode, latestMessageUuid)
      .doOnSuccess { messageTable.insertNewMessages(it) }
      .doOnSuccess { newMessagesSubject.onNext(it) }
      .map(::filterCurrentMessage)

  Single
    .fromCallable { accessCodeSettings.accessCode to messageTable.latestUUID }
    .flatMap { (accessCode, latestMessageUuid) ->
      loadFromDatabase()
        .switchIfEmpty(loadCacheEmitAndMap(accessCode, latestMessageUuid))
    }
    .subscribe(::showNotification)
}
```

With this approach I have the following problem:

- If two notifications arrive one after another, both can observe that respective `uuid`s are not in the database, so both will load from the server new messages, possible the same set of messages, both will save messages in the database, and both will emit messages in the `newMessages` subject. So, I’ll end up with duplicated messages.

  - I can’t `synchronize` the method that fetches messages, because it’s also an observable and I don’t want to make it blocking.

How would you design an observable stream, to guarantee that the `newMessages` subject is correct?

Answer (score 0):

You can create an internal service that handles requests for messages.

```
fun requestMessage( message: UUID ): Single<UserMessage>
```

It would be responsible for fetching a message, if necessary, by going to the server. Internally, it would use a cache indexed by the UUID. Here is an approach I have found useful:

```
val messageCache: Map<UUID, BehaviorSubject<UserMessage>> = Maps.newConcurrentMap();
```

The implementation of `requestMessage()` looks like:

```
return messageCache.computeIfAbsent(message, id -> {
   val res: BehaviorSubject.<UserMessage>create()
   getMessage(id).subscribe(res)
   return res.take(1).toSingle()
  })
```

(Pardon my bad Kotlin syntax)  This will always return an observable that has the message eventually. The `ConcurrentHashMap` ensures that only one service request is issued for any message ID.